# Is there a way to redirect DNS traffic to ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, proxy, tunnel

I am trying to get a barebone solutions similar to different smart dns proxies available .

Now I am able to get one part done, by using , ssh tunneling and creating dynamic forward.

```
host myserver
User root
    HostName MyIP
    IdentityFile <MyKey>
    DynamicForward 4444
```

Now this works when I have a browser and I am able to set the sock proxy.

But what

1. I want is to have a DNS server running (similar to dnsmasq).
2. Configure the DNS Server on my router.
3. Tunnel all traffic through ssh.

Comment: Which operating system and software are being used here?

Answer (score 4):

[sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) could be helpful:

> Transparent proxy server that works as a poor man's VPN. Forwards over ssh. Doesn't require admin. Works with Linux and MacOS. Supports DNS tunneling.

It allows you to forward all your traffic over SSH to a server, [including DNS](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manpage.html?highlight=dns#cmdoption-sshuttle-dns).

I have not used it myself, but perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. Dnsmasq can't just ask a SOCKS proxy to resolve names, as there is no such SOCKS protocol command; the proxy only has a command that would take a domain name + port *and* immediately connect to it, while the client never actually learns the IP address that was used. (And in addition, DNS is *a bit more* than just IP address lookups, so even if such a function *was* available you still couldn't properly emulate DNS on top of it.)

However, some DNS resolvers (not Dnsmasq) can talk to a *real* DNS server through an SSH tunnel. DNS servers are required to support TCP, so you could use a standard `ssh -L` tunnel and point it to some remote server. Dnsmasq won't work (it always tries UDP first), but Unbound can be told to always query over TCP. A resolver that uses DoT (DNS over TLS) or DoH would also work, as those currently are also TCP-based.

I would really recommend an IP-layer tunnel (a VPN) instead of SOCKS, though. While you can survive for a long time with only TCP, plenty of programs do require UDP as well, and it's overall much simpler to route everything over an IP tunnel than it is to do the same over SOCKS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Saaru's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1742286/643441), I was able to get sshuttle to proxy *only* DNS requests with a command like the following:

```bash
sshuttle --dns -r username@host \
    --ns-hosts=dns01.example.com,dns02.example.com \
    0/0:53 ::/0:53
```

Comment: Maybe want to add this as a comment to that answer or edit that answer to include this useful info, perhaps? Cheers! :)